# interactive object?

Tags: actionscript

is there a easy method to create objects that you can interact with the mouse in actionscript. Something like a few lines of code ?

Comment: This question isn't very clear. Could you explain more about how you want to interact with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite(); // create a new sprite.
sprite.graphics.beginFill(0); // set fill color to black
sprite.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100); // draw a square
addChild(sprite); // add the sprite to the display list making it appear on screen.
sprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown); // add responders for mouse interaction.
sprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);

function onMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void {
   // When the mouse button is released over the object, this code executes.
   Sprite(event.target).startDrag(); // make the object follow the mouse.
}

function onMouseUp(event:MouseEvent):void {
   // When the mouse button is pressed over the object, this code executes.
   Sprite(event.target).stopDrag(); // make the object stop following the mouse.
}
```